# How much does a Bag of Holding weigh when it is infused by an artificer from a normal backpack (using the Replicate Magic Item infusion)?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, equipment, weight, artificer-infusions

I searched for an answer to this question, but could not find one.

The ["Infusing an Item"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#InfusinganItem) section of the artificer's [Infuse Item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#InfuseItem-1131631) feature description states:

> Whenever you finish a long rest, you can touch a nonmagical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, turning it into a magic item.

Once my artificer achieved the appropriate level, he chose the [Replicate Magic Item](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#ReplicateMagicItem) infusion for a *Bag of Holding*.  This he fashioned from his existing [backpack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/backpack), which has a PHB weight of 5 lbs.  However, a [*Bag of Holding*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) normally weighs 15 lbs.

Which weight do I use for my encumbrance considerations: 5 lbs. or 15 lbs.?

Comment: I don't see the confusion here.  The artificer was following a recipe to make a BoH.  One of the _ingredients_ had a weight of 5 lbs, but that seems irrelevant - the creation was successful, the backpack doesn't exist any more, and the artificer now has a BoH (which weighs 15 lbs).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The (infused) Bag of Holding weighs as much as a (non-infused) Bag of Holding

When you use the Replicate Magic Item infusion, you are... replicating a magic item:

> Using this infusion, you replicate a particular magic item.

This is reinforced by the description of the Infuse Item feature (emphasis added):

> At 2nd level, you gain the ability to imbue mundane items with certain magical infusions. The magic items you create with this feature are effectively prototypes of **permanent items.** [...]  you can touch a non-magical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions, **turning it into a magic item.**

So, the backpack that was infused to create a Bag of Holding is literally a Bag of Holding as long as it remains infused. **Unless otherwise noted, the properties of the item are identical to the non-infusion-based version of the magic item being replicated.** That includes the item's weight.